# Any mnemonic tip for boolean?

Tags: boolean, mnemonics

I guess this is trivial for most of good<sup>1</sup> programmers, but I'm so used to programming using `true` and `false`<sup>2</sup> that when I encounter 0 and 1, I can never remember which one means true and which one means false.

Any suggestions?

<sup>1</sup>Good: [I mean one who knows C, of course](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html) :)
<sup>2</sup>I am a Java developer, as you have guessed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't you ever noticed that everyday items' power switches use a [circle for off, and a line for on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_symbol)?

It's not much of a jump to link them up.

Off = circle = zero = false

On = line = one = true

Comment: Yeah, use something like a closed circuit to indicate off, and something like an open circuit to indicate on.  Who thought up that standard?

Answer (score 9):

The mnemonic is "how much truth is in this?"  Zero integer means zero truth.  Anything else is nonzero truth. :)

Comment: Indeed, note the "anything nonzero is truth"! Anything nonzero is usually interpreted as `true`.

Comment: Ah, but in some languages, -1 is also true.  How can you have negative truth?

Comment: The same way you can have 27 or [1,5] or "falsehood\n" truth: magic.

Comment: Also: 'some languages'?  Are there any languages that allow interpretation of an arbitrary value in boolean context where -1 *isn't* true?

Comment: "At least one sheep in Scotland is black on one side" - I don't know every single language, therefore I cannot say "every" or even "most" so some is the safest term.

Comment: Seems a little sheepish to me.

Comment: Would it blow your mind if I pointed out that this is not a mnemonic? :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I dunno, would it blow your mind to find out that "mnemonic device" means "trick for aiding memory" and is not actually limited to retarded nursery rhymes that form initialisms?

Answer (score 4):

I have a co-worker who simply has a Post-It note on his wall beside his desk:

> False = 0
>   True != 0

Answer (score 4):

If you are really having that much trouble with it, I would use the language to abstract it away.

e.g. in C

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

In general I would avoid having constants lying around in code anyways.

Consider,

```
if(my_var == TRUE)
```

as opposed to,

```
if(my_var == 1)
```

Though, here again you need to make sure you are testing for the right thing,

```
if(my_var != FALSE)
```

will catch more cases.

Cheers!

Christian

Comment: Never test for true or false using a comparison operator.  That's redundant and sometimes error-prone.  Use "if(my_var)" instead.

Answer (score 3):

"Oh No!"
(Oh == 0)

Answer (score 3):

This is complicated by the fact that in the shell (sh, bash) true is 0 and false is 1:

```
$ true
$ echo $?
0
$ false
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: that's because there's only one 0 and only one successful outcome, but there are as possible errors as there are positive return codes :)

Comment: in shells i don't think of return codes as true/false, rather as error code.  obviously 0 means no error.

Comment: They can be used in conditional statements, so they are as boolean as are integers in C.

Comment: These aren't booleans per se. They're return codes. It's not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Remember "nothing == false", "something == true"

Answer (score 2):

No mnemonic - and it gets even more complex if you come from a hardware background.  But for programmers, just ask the question:

Is any bit set?

The answer is either true or false, and is the result.  Only 0 (even in signed integers) has no bits set.

-Adam

Comment: Except for the old ones-compliment machines! I remember tracing a bug on a CDC-Cyber mainframe in school when ALL the conditions were true making all the bits 1 which is the 2nd representation for 0!

Comment: Ouch!  One's complement machines leave me shivering.  On the other hand, I never did like how unbalanced twos complement is - how the negative numbers always got one more than the positive numbers.  It's like a tug of war where the bad guys always win by just a little bit...

Answer (score 1):

Map both to `On` and `Off`.  I think most programmers would map both sets the same way: 1/true both going to 'On', while 0/false both go to 'Off'.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language.

- **C**: `( 0 ? "never happens" : "false")` and `( 1 ? "true" : "never happens")`
- **Ruby**, **ELisp**: both `0` and `1` are true
- **bash** (or **cmd.exe**): the `true` command (from coreutils) exits with a `0` status code and the `false` command exits with a non-zero status code

Many modern popular programming languages have strong C heritage therefore they consider `0` to be false and `1` (or any non-zero numbers) to be true.

Don't use mnemonics for boolean, use your language's idioms to test trueness.

Answer (score 0):

love c - because you can't multiply lies. :)